# How to connect HBase with PHP or other

Tags: hadoop, hbase

am new to HBase. currently am installed HBase as a standalone mode and i tried to start HBase master, its working. I know is there a API for HBase connectivity but i like to know how to connect HBase from API and get the results.

Is there any tutorial for this, please help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

you can use a client like : [pop_hbase](https://github.com/pop/pop_hbase)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tested with the Pop_HBase Code. Its return the error even the Hbase running.

Comment: pop_hbase uses hbase rest server instead of directly going with thrift. so as the tutorial shows (in link) you need to start hbase rest server aswell.

Comment: yes correct, but how can i start the HBase rest server. its throwing error when i start.

Answer (score 1):

check out the Thrift API for HBase:
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi

There are definitely PHP connectivity, as well as many other languages.

Comment: if you have a working sample in php of thrift access to hbase I would like to get it, I just can't get any working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HBase restful API http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.20.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/stargate/package-summary.html#package_description

Comment: Thanks for your help. I go through the links but how can i install the stargate package. there is no link for download stargate API. Thanks in advance